# Django Haystack Whoosh Backend and Partial Search

Tags: django, django-haystack

i'm using django haystack 1.27.
I can search. That's great. But how can i search after partial words?

for example:

search after: OREM, OR, EM

Word: LOREM

Result: LOREM

search_indexes.py

```
class NewsIndex(SearchIndex):
    text = CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    date = DateTimeField(model_attr='creation_date')
    def get_model(self):
        return News

    def index_queryset(self):
        return self.get_model().objects.get_published_models(TOWN, News)

site.register(News, NewsIndex)
```

views.py

```
def search(request):
    order = self.request.GET.get("order", None)
    sqs = SearchQuerySet()
    if order:
        ...
        sqs = sqs.order_by(order + "date")

    search_template = SearchView(template='general/search.html',
                                 searchqueryset=sqs)(request)
```

The ordering was not difficult.

I thought a search index engine includes partial search :/.
Does Whoosh supportes this functionality?
I've tested: autocomplete function, but no results for "EM", JUST "LOR".

Comment: The documentation for the current beta version [http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/autocomplete.html](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/autocomplete.html) suggests you can now do this, but it looks to me like the current stable version might not support it. I'm looking into the same problem myself so I'll let you know if I solve it.

Answer (score 7):

Try to use `NgramField` instead of `CharField`.

It will generate all possible `Ngrams` to be indexed.
Disadvantages of using `NgramField` is making the index files become very large.
Mine has size of 2MB just for 24 records.

You may want to use `EdgeNgramField` instead. It excludes many possibilities.

For instance:

Data: 'documentation'

Using NgramField:
Query : 'ocument'
Result : 'documentation'

Using EdgeNgramField:
Query : 'ocument'
Result : None